Yii2 Redirect Back to Login Page Missing Styles Until Page Refresh
I’m experiencing an issue with my Yii2 application where the login page styles are not properly applied after being redirected from the password recovery form. The issue resolves itself after manually refreshing the page in the browser.
Details
Here’s the flow:

Access the Login Page: When I visit http://myapp/user/login, the
login page loads correctly with all Bootstrap styles and inline CSS
applied.
Click "Forgot Password": Clicking on the "Forgot Password" link
takes me to http://myapp/user/forgot, where I can submit my email to
receive a recovery link.
Submit Recovery Form: After submitting the form, the page redirects
back to the login page (http://myapp/user/login), but the login
page appears unstyled (no Bootstrap or inline CSS applied).
Refresh Page: Manually refreshing the page restores the correct
styles

Observations

The login page uses a custom layout (@app/views/layouts/login) and
includes both Bootstrap classes and inline CSS.
No errors appear in the browser console, and all CSS files are loaded
correctly according to the Network tab.
This issue occurs only after the redirect from the recovery page.
Accessing the login page directly works fine.


Are you maybe displaying some flash message after submitting recovery form? If you are then I would recommend checking for broken html code (unclosed element or something like that) in that message.
